# Change Semantic UI Tabs on click of some button in other component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have the following code in my component, where `A` nad `B` are my other components and `SomeComponent` is where I am rendering `A` and `B` along with the `TabExampleSecondaryPointing` component.

```
import { Tab } from 'semantic-ui-react';

const panes = [
  { menuItem: 'A', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false}> <A/> </Tab.Pane> },
  { menuItem: 'B', render: () => <Tab.Pane attached={false} > <B/> </Tab.Pane> },
]

const TabExampleSecondaryPointing = () => (
   <Tab menu={{ secondary: true, pointing: true }} panes={panes} />
)

class SomeComponent extends Component {
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
           <TabExampleSecondaryPointing />
        </div>
      );
  }
}
```

What I want to do is when I click some button inside of component `A` (which is currently active in A Tab) the current or Active Tab should switch to B Tab. I am using Tabs component of Semantic UI for React. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

[@Vibhor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9187617/vibhor-sharma) in the interest of someone else landing on this answer, and perhaps helping you to improve your solution, I would encourage you to take a look at the [controlled examples for Tabs on the SUIR documentation](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/tab#tab-example-active-index).

What you have proposed and implemented as your solution is definitely a workaround. You are using the DOM to simulate a click event to change the auto controlled state of that component. What you want to do is directly control that state yourself. Out of the box, many SUIR components are handling the state themselves.

I put together a CodeSandbox example for you here showing how this would work with an internal component state extending upon the example in the SUIR docs:

https://codesandbox.io/s/k9ozm3w5n7

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { Button, Container, Tab } from "semantic-ui-react";

class TabExampleActiveIndex extends Component {
  state = { activeIndex: 1 };

  handleRangeChange = e => this.setState({ activeIndex: e.target.value });
  handleTabChange = (e, { activeIndex }) => this.setState({ activeIndex });

  render() {
    const { activeIndex } = this.state;

    const panes = [
      {
        menuItem: "Tab 1",
        render: () => (
          <Tab.Pane>
            Tab 1 Content{" "}
            <Button
              content="Tab 2"
              onClick={this.handleRangeChange}
              value={1}
            />
          </Tab.Pane>
        )
      },
      {
        menuItem: "Tab 2",
        render: () => (
          <Tab.Pane>
            Tab 2 Content{" "}
            <Button
              content="Tab 3"
              onClick={this.handleRangeChange}
              value={2}
            />
          </Tab.Pane>
        )
      },
      {
        menuItem: "Tab 3",
        render: () => (
          <Tab.Pane>
            Tab 3 Content{" "}
            <Button
              content="Tab 1"
              onClick={this.handleRangeChange}
              value={0}
            />
          </Tab.Pane>
        )
      }
    ];

    return (
      <div>
        <div>activeIndex: {activeIndex}</div>
        <input
          type="range"
          max="2"
          value={activeIndex}
          onChange={this.handleRangeChange}
        />
        <Tab
          panes={panes}
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TabExampleActiveIndex;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 (<any>$('.menu .item')).tab('change tab', 'tab-name');
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Comment: OP is about Semantic UI React while this answer uses JQuery.